# Git pre-commit hook to check spurious spaces

Tags: git

I would like to make a pre-commit hook which:

- forbide commit if I have spurious space
- allow it in other way.

That is my actually code

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Vérifier avant un commit que l'on n'a pas mis de spurious spaces.
a=$(git diff --check | wc -c)
if [ $a -gt 0 ]
then
 echo "Spurious space"
 exit 1
else
  echo "ok"
fi
```

If I run manually the script in a diff with spurious spaces, I obtain "Spurious space". That is perfect. But if I run it as a pre-commit hook, I always obtain "ok".

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: I've flagged this for migration to StackOverflow (please be patient while it gets the appropriate attention).  `git` questions can be difficult to figure out where they go.  For future reference, please see [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) on our meta site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing here is that you need to compare what is *to be committed*, rather than what's in the working directory, against the `HEAD` revision.  This is easily done with `git diff --cached` (which can be mixed with `--check`).

As a smaller improvement, `git diff --check` (with or without `--cached`) already:

> Exits with non-zero status if problems are found.

(see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)).  Thus, if you're willing to let the diff itself show on the screen:

```
#! /bin/sh
git diff --check --cached
```

should suffice as the entirety of the pre-commit hook.  If you want to run additional tests if there are no white-space errors:

```
#! /bin/sh
git diff --check --cached || exit $?
... additional tests here ...
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I understand well, the problem was the non use of --cached ?

Comment: Yes.  Without `--cached`, diff compares the current working directory (shown as the new or `b` version) vs staged content (old or `a` version).  With `--cached`, diff compares staged vs `HEAD`.