# git precommit and LaTeX

Tags: git, latex

I use git to manage some LaTeX package.

I would like to add a pre-commit hook, to check if I have forgotten % at the lines' end, like needed in LaTeX to prevent spurious space.

For now, I have a minimal pre-commit, which test only the blank spaces at ends of lines, but not the forgotten %.

```
#! /bin/sh
git diff --check --cached || exit $?
(See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21178251/3206025)
```

.

I was not able to find in the handbook of git where a I could configure the --check option.

For example, these lines should not be commited:

```
\newcommmand{\toto}{
     \command
}
```

But theses lines, yes:

```
\newcommmand{\toto}{%
     \command%
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to configure the `--check` option. You will have to extend your pre-commit hook to check for trailing `%` yourself.

Comment: ok. So I have to learn bash script...

Comment: You can write git hooks in a multitude of languages for example in python or ruby. Just search for git hooks in your prefered language.

Comment: I will look more, before doing my own... maybe there is someonde who done it.

Comment: Ok, my hook is available https://github.com/maieul/git-hooks/blob/master/pre-commit-latex

Comment: I guess it would make sense if you wrote an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my own hook.

It checks the .dtx files:

- allow empty lines
- allow lines begining with %
- forbide lines without % at end
- forbide lines with space before final %

The hook is available on https://github.com/maieul/git-hooks/blob/master/pre-commit-latex. You just to have python on you computer, push it in the .git/hooks folder, and make it executable.

And in French http://geekographie.maieul.net/Un-hook-de-pre-commit-pour-s